# Trouble in reading json data in angularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to read a json file which contains the list of songs and a url to the image

```
{"songs" : [
{
    "SongName" : "Broken Dreams",
    "image" : "img/browser.svg"
},
{
    "SongName" : "My heart goes on",
    "image" : "img/browser.svg"
},
{
    "SongName" : "Summer of 69",
    "image" : "img/browser.svg"
},
{
    "SongName" : "Broken Hearted Girl",
    "image" : "img/browser.svg"
},
{
    "SongName" : "American idiot",
        "image" : "img/browser.svg"
    }
]}
```

but the basic issue is when I use the $http.get(), it reads the json but I am not able to assign it to the angularJS object, here is my angularJS code

```
var app = angular.module('TheSlideShow', []);
        app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

            $scope.test = "this is a test string";
            $scope.songList = {};

                $http.get("Data/SongList.json", ['$scope']).success(function(List){ $scope.songList  = List.songs;  console.log("The Length : " + $scope.songList.length);});

            for(var i = 0; i< $scope.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log("loop number" + i);
                }

        }]);
```

The Length field gives the result as 5 but my for loop does not run even for a single time..

Comment: The quesion you have linked is based on jquery and i am looking for angularJS way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of mistakes

1. You should not pass `$scope` to `$http.get`
2. You can not get `$scope.songList` value outside ajax directictly, the value is getting populated through ajax call, so you need to run for loop inside ajax success

**Code**

```
$http.get("Data/SongList.json").success(function(List){ 
  $scope.songList  = List.songs;  
  console.log("The Length : " + $scope.songList.length);
  for(var i = 0; i< $scope.songList.length; i++)
  {
     console.log("loop number" + i);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reminding me about the $scope variable, I was using the hit and trial method and forgot to remove it. I want to use the data from the json into another function is there any other way to do it? I mean how I could pass my song list to the different function?

Comment: does that javascript function inside inside controller?

Comment: Yes! that function would be inside the same controller!

Comment: you could easily pass it as param like `$scope.someFunction($scope.songList)` & the function would be `$scope.someFunction  = function(songs){ //you could songs here }`